# How to select a shape and round the attribute field?

Tags: python, modelbuilder

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

if arcpy.Exists("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\adverse_skid_area.shp"): arcpy.Delete_management("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\adverse_skid_area.shp")
if arcpy.Exists("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\comments.shp"): arcpy.Delete_management("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\comments.shp")
if arcpy.Exists("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\desig_crossing.shp"): arcpy.Delete_management("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\desig_crossing.shp")

# Local variables:
adverse_skid_area = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\adverse_skid_area"
comments = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\comments"
desig_crossing = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\desig_crossing"
Temp_LP_Layers = "F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers"
Temp_LP_Layers__2_ = Temp_LP_Layers

# Process: Feature Class To Shapefile (multiple)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\adverse_skid_area;F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\comments;F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers_GDB\\Temp_LP_Layers.gdb\\desig_crossing", Temp_LP_Layers)


arcpy.CalculateField_management("F:\\Atco_gis\\temp_shapefiles\\Temp_LP_Layers\\adverse_skid_area.shp","PERIMETER","!Shape_Area! / 10000","PYTHON")

round(!PERIMETER!, 2)
```

How do I select the adverse_skid_area.shp perimeter attribute and round the field to 0.00 (two decimal places?)

Comment: Try to change your calculate field expression to `"round((!Shape_Area! / 10000),2)"`

Comment: (Shape area is not perimiter, shape length is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there seems to be a confusion between area and perimeter. In a geodatabase, you can use the !shape_area! field for the area and the !shape_length! field for the perimeter (or the length if the feature is a line and not a polygon). With a shapefile, those fields are not automatically updated, so I would avoid using them. It is better to compute your "perimeter" value based on the !shape! field.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("your_shp.shp","PERIMETER","round((!Shape.length! / 10000"),2),"PYTHON")
```

note that you can also specify the unit of your calculation to increase the readability. For instance, for areas in hectares, you can directly use

```
  arcpy.CalculateField_management("your_shp.shp","AREA_ha","round(!Shape.area@HECTARES!,2)","PYTHON")
```

in the field calculator.  More details [in ArcGIS help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F885F6AD331240ACB2DBDDA70151146D)

Finally, it can be usefull to store the most precise value, so I suggest that you don't round within the field but only the display of the field (so that you don't need to duplicate the same info or to constantly verify that the two fields are up-to-date):

For the attribute table, you can right-click on your "perimeter" field > go to properties > click on the "numeric" button and select the number of decimal that you want to show.

For labels, you can use display expression (right click on the layer > properties > label > click on the expression button, enter (example in vbscript)

```
Round([Shape_area]/10000,2)
```

(As a remark, I also suggest that you don't convert your geodatabase to shapefile, because geodatabase is most of the time more powerful.)